# Symfony 4 - route : "The requested URL was not found on this server"

Tags: php, symfony, routes, http-status-code-404, symfony4

this is my first post so i'll try to be understandable.

I am starting with symfony, and there is a problem i can't resolve alone.

This is my controller, and I am working with WAMP.
When my Url is "mysite.local", it work normally, and it show me what it should (thanks to the home() function). But when my Url is "mysite.local/hello", i have the following error.

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) PHP/7.4.0 Server at mysite.local Port 80

I guess this is normal as i didn't created any file named "hello", but it's working in the formation i am following.

Could you help me please ? Thank you

```
<?php


namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
/**
 * @Route("/hello", name="hello")
 */

public function hello()
{
    return new Response("Bonjour ...");
}
/**
 *@Route("/", name="homepage");
 */

public function home(){
    $prenoms = ["Lior" => 17 , "Joseph" => 12, "Anne" => 55];
    return $this->render("home.html.twig",
        [
            'title' => "Bonjour a tous :)",
            'age' => "31 ",
            'tableau' => $prenoms,
        ]); 
}
```

}

?>

Comment: Hello there. Do you have the route defined for `hello`? Normally in MVC frameworks the route calls the controller's function. If `mysite.local` works that is because route `/` is mapped to `home()` function of the controller. The error message suggests that `/hello` does not exist. Please check

Comment: @kendrick where is your routes definition code?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Please try with

`mysite.local/index.php/hello`

If that works, that means either .htaccess file is missing or mod_rewrite is not enabled on apache server.

first you can run

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

to add .htaccess automatically and test, if route works then everything is fine.

otherwise you've to edit `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf` file and enable `mod_rewrite`

Comment: hello, Thank you for your answer : this URL (mysite.local/index.php/hello) works. But where should i run the command ? In the C:/wamp64 file, or directly in C:/wamp64/www/mysite ?

Comment: run the command in project directory i.e. C:/wamp64/www/mysite

Comment: @KendrickLarlar Also you've to run this command `composer require symfony/apache-pack`, I've updated my answer as well.

Comment: @KendrickLarlar Kindly mark my answer as correct if it worked for you. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, it's works

Comment: You saved my day Sir! I also want to add that for me this issue caused by wrong virtual host file setup and configuration. For the same directive config if I put it here /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf - it will work and if I put it here /etc/httpd/conf.d/custom.conf - it will not work . As you can see that is because ssl.conf overridden the custom.conf - not what I expected.

Answer (score 4):

apache is missing on you server to add .htaccess file

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

Comment: Besides this, make sure you have `a2enmod rewrite` apache rewrite mod on (you can just run it on local or in apache container and it will say if it's already enabled or not).

Answer (score 0):

Need to create `.htaccess` file with `composer` above way, but the `symfony/apache-pack` by default will not execute, you need to put `y`

or create `.htaccess` file manually by copying the below content inside `public` folder, where `index.php` file lives, then all routes will work.

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options +FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/index" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/index.php" but be rewritten to "/index.php/index".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```