# Production server configuration to work with autoloader/htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

I made a Symfony App which works perfectly locally but transferring my actual status to the live production server has been tricky.

The last problem I am having is none of the /blalbla works.

So the / works, but when I try to load any of the other it won't.

The difference is. On my local I have a .htacces and on prod I had to disable is since it causing me this:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache/2.4.41 Server at website Port 80

When I disable my `.htacces` I can get to / route but not any other.

Where do I even start?

I'm guessing I need a `.htaccess`?

Here it is (if you need it)

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apache is missing on you server to add .htaccess file to access other routes instead of / only

my solution for that : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549873/8808725